# How to tell "if on development environment"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'd like to add a condition to my C# program i'm develop in Visual Studio:

```
#If onEditor 
   do something
```

In Unity exists `if Application.isEditor`

Does exists something in 'regular' (WinForms or ASP.NET) C# application on Visual Studio?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343053/detecting-if-a-program-was-run-by-visual-studio-as-opposed-to-run-from-windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#if` are compile directives, so whatever goes there will be checked on compile time, and not on runtime. There is `#if DEBUG` which effectively means 'this was build in debug mode', rather than 'release mode'. It doesn't tell anything about the origin of the running if your program.

I think what you are looking for is [`Debugger.IsAttached`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached): it checks if a debugger is attached. If that it `true`, the program is either ran from Visual Studio, or a debugger was attached later on.

Comment: or for anti-debugging you could PInvoke `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent`

Answer (score 3):

Use this in Visual Studio to test if you're running in Debug mode:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
   Debugger.Break();
}
```

Use `#if DEBUG` to conditionally compile code in - either debug mode or release mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#if DEBUG
```

`DEBUG` constant is defined for Debug configuration in all default Visual Studio project templates.

Comment: or `Debugger.IsAttached` depending on the needs